# Insert new line after semicolon in SQL* Plus

Tags: sqlplus

I want to run an insert script in SQL Plus on a table in which the value has a new line after semicolon. I'm able to insert new lines using command

```
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
```

But when I try to insert a string which has a new line after a semicolon, it gives error

```
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

and

```
unknown command beginning "Bye;',..." - rest of line ignored.
```

when I try to insert like this

```
INSERT INTO M_TABLE VALUES('Hi!
My Name is Tom;
Bye', 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL*Plus is interpreting the semicolon as a statement terminator.

You can change that to another character, or temporarily stop it being recognised [via the client settings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG109):

```
set sqlterminator off

INSERT INTO M_TABLE VALUES('Hi!
My Name is Tom;
Bye', 0)
/

set sqlterminator on
```

The overall insert statement now *has* to be [ended and submitted with a slash on a new line](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref273), since just sticking a semicolon on the end now won't be recognised.